# How to automatically set the current working file to compile and debug when using visual studio code?

Tags: c, debugging, visual-studio-code

I saw there is now a [support for C/C++ on Visual Studio Code](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/31/cc-extension-for-visual-studio-code/).

I use OS X 10.11.6 with lldb installed.

But I just wonder how to debug the current working C file, without modifying the launch.json, that is to say, no matter which file I am working on, A.c/B.c/C.c, when I start to debug, VSC could compile the according file and attach to it.

And furthermore, could VSC compile the code first?

**My launch.json is:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "C++ Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/lab20/lab20b/skating",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "linux": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            },
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb"
            },
            "windows": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "C++ Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/lab20/lab20b/skating",
            "processId": "${command.pickProcess}",
            "linux": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            },
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb"
            },
            "windows": {
                "MIMode": "gdb"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't find any explaination on these properties with the official documents.

Comment: Windows uses backslashes as path separator, not forward slashes.

Comment: @paddy Thanks, I use os x :)

Comment: Oh sorry, I just saw "Visual Studio" and didn't realise MS was trying to inexplicably expand into the Mac market.  Good luck to them.... =/  In any case, it looks like you're specifying the `.c` source file as the compiled binary to attach the debugger.  That's incorrect.  You need to specify the name of the actual binary being built, not the source.

Comment: @paddy Thanks. It works, so it means I need to compile it by myself everytime?

Comment: @paddy There is also MSVC for Linux. Btw it doesn't care about back or forward slashes because in Windows most APIs support forward slashes and compilers always accept both types